# Collections.frequency() method giving output as zero?

Tags: java, list, collections, char, frequency

This code prints a value of "0":

```
String name = "aaa";
char[] mychar = new char[name.length()];
mychar = name.toCharArray();
List<char[]> values = Arrays.asList(mychar);
int m = Collections.frequency(values, 'a'); 
System.out.println(m);
```

Why?

Comment: Because `Arrays.asList` gives you a `List<char[]>`, not a `List<Character>`.

Comment: What should I do inorder to get the correct output?

Comment: There's no way to do it in one line before Java 8.  With Java 8, you could write `string.chars().filter(c -> c == 'a').count()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections#frequency` iterates through a `List`, counting the number of elements that are equal to the argument passed to the method.

In your example, each element of your `List` is an **array** of the primitive type, `char`, but you're attempting to find a single `char` within the `List`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: What should I do then inorder to get the correct output?

Comment: You should use `List<Character>` instead and not add the array to it, but the `char`s themselves.